# Problems recaptcha FirebaseAuth in Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I made request to verifyPhoneNumber on mode release app, I received this error

> this request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that play integrity checks, and recaptcha checks were unsuccessful. please try again, or check the logcat for more details

On mode debug it open browser and made recaptcha normally.

I already add SHA-1 and SHA-256 of release, debug and playstore in Firebase and updated my google-services.json, but the problem persist.

I tryed add `implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'` but same error. I saw some people told to enabled Android Device Verification in GCP but I not found this service.

Somebody have some sugestion?

Comment: Have you checked that the package name in your firebase project is the same as the app bundle id in your application? those must match.

Comment: @Matias It's same